# Change history looks weird if same edit committed by two people fast

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list

> [We apparently committed the same edit within 1 second. :p The change history looks weird...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185056/intercommunication-between-threads#comment443601_185056)

When looking at the [Revision History](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/185056/revisions) of the question, edit 2 added a tag, and edit 3 shows as being empty (because it was making the same edit).

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but it seems weird at the very least. Perhaps the edit should have been rejected saying to reload the page because something changed in the meantime?

Comment: Reproduced: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/404766/revisions